# Rephrasing using verb (prohibit)

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, spoken-english

can I rephrase " **Our religion prohibit us from drinking alcohol** "
to be " **Our religion prohibit drinking alcohol on us**",  precisely I want to know if "**on us**" is applicable here ??

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an "s" to your ***prohibit*** (3rd person singular).

You cannot prohibit something ***on*** someone else. But you can ***impose a ban on drinking alcohol*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impose)), though I wouldn't use this strong phrase in connection with religion unless you want to criticise it.

You could maybe say

> Our religion does not allow us to drink alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

> " Our religion prohibit drinking alcohol on us", precisely I want to
> know if "on us" is applicable here

Precisely, No.

Answer (score 0):

No, using "on us" is not applicable in this situation.

More correct phrasing would be: `Our religion prohibits us from drinking alcohol.`